# ffmpeg erases the last part of audio in the video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I use following encoding option.

```
ffmpeg  -i input.wmv -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -strict -2 /root/output.mp4;
```

But sometimes last 5~30 seconds audio is erased.
Total video duration is about 3 mins.
what do you think the problem is?

Is this related to computer performance? I use quadcore, 4G ram.

Comment: Not related to comp specs. Run `ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c copy temp.wmv` and see if all audio is copied over.

Comment: yes, audio is certainly copied. Above ffmpeg works fine for my 2 computers, but  another computer keep erasing audio of last seconds.

Comment: Are they the same ffmpeg version?

Comment: yes, same version

Comment: Post your complete uncut command line and console output for a successful and failing case...